# Symfony Insert or update Doctrine entity with unique constraints

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**Problem**

I have this business case where administrators need to import a medium sized list of participants, max 10,000 records. Entity has a unique constraint on 4 fields (name, surname, email and event id). What would be the best approach to update or insert new records into database?

It could be that the list is imported once, then more participants are appended to the excel file, maybe some extra non-unique fields are changed on existing participants and the file is imported again.

**Things I've tried**

1. The initial idea was to use doctrine's `merge()` function, but that causes constraint violation, my guess would be because my object does not contain an id
2. Second approach was to flush every iteration and catch the exception, but this causes entity manager to close. I tried resetting it to no avail. It could be possible to try and persist entities that don't throw an exception and do another iteration on entities that cause an exception, but this would mean sending 10,000 queries
3. Another idea is to select all existing participants, put them inside an array collection and call `exists()` or `filter()` on the collection every iteration, but this causes filter function to be called on every collection element, so that would be 10,000 x 10,000 = 100,000,000 checks in the end, terrible performance wise
4. Another thought is to fetch existing participants and concat unique fields and put them inside a hashmap, this could work in theory
5. My last idea is to try and insert everything in chunks of 100. If the insertion is successful we move to another chunk of 100. If chunk throws a constraint violation, we split the chunk into smaller chunks of 10 and try to do the same thing. Just no idea how this would perform in a worst case scenario

---

**My code**

Entity:

```
class Person implements Comparable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var object
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="extras", type="object")
     */
    private $extras;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Event")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $event;

<...>

    public function compareTo($other)
    {
        if(get_class($other) == Person::class)
        {
            if($other->getName() == $this->name
                && $other->getSurname() == $this->surname
                && $other->getEmail() == $this->email
                && $other->getEvent() == $this->event)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public function postTicketsAction(Request $request, Event $event)
    {
<...>
        if($form->isValid())
        {
<...>
            while($iterator->valid())
            {
<...>
                $person = new Person();
                $person
                    ->setEvent($event)
                    ->setName($name)
                    ->setSurname($surname)
                    ->setEmail($email)
                    ->setExtras($extras)
                ;

                $em->merge($person);
<...>
            }

            dump($failedPeople);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting some fresh air, I decided to use field slugs as an approach to check existing records.

Since we want to check for uniqueness we will generate a string with concatenated unique fields. But we also need an object reference to merge into database. This is solved by custom repository query.

This is quite fast since this is a db query.

**PersonRepository.php**

```
<...>
public function getSlugs(Event $event)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')->createQueryBuilder('p');

        $qb->select('CONCAT(p.name, \'-\', p.surname, \'-\', p.email, \'-\', IDENTITY(p.event)) slug, p obj')
            ->where($qb->expr()->eq('p.event', $event->getId()))
        ;

        $res = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

        return [
            'slugs' => array_column($res, 'slug'),
            'objects' => array_column($res, 'obj')
        ];
    }
<...>
```

Next we implement this into controller

**PersonController.php**

```
public function postPeopleAction(Request $request, Event $event)
{
<...>
    // Handle file upload and iterator creation
<...>
    $existingPeople = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')->getSlugs($event);

    while($iterator->valid())
    {
        $row = $iterator->current()->getRowIndex();

        $name = $sheet->getCell($requiredColumns['name'] . $row)->getValue();
        $surname = $sheet->getCell($requiredColumns['surname'] . $row)->getValue();
        $email = $sheet->getCell($requiredColumns['email'] . $row)->getValue();

        $search = "$name-$surname-$email-$eventId";
        $indexOfPerson = array_search($search, $existingPeople['slugs']);

        // person already exists
        if($indexOfPerson > -1)
        {
            $person = $existingPeople['objects'][$indexOfPerson];
            $person->setExtras($extras);
            $em->merge($person);
        }
        // this is a new person
        else
        {
            $person = new Person();
            $person
                ->setEvent($event)
                ->setName($name)
                ->setSurname($surname)
                ->setEmail($email)
                ->setExtras($extras)
            ;

            $em->persist($person);
        }

        $iterator->next();
    }

    $em->flush();
}
```